# What is the difference between Flux.map{ - } and Flux.flatMap{ Flux.just(-) } in Spring Webflux

Tags: spring-webflux

While learning Webflux, I had the following questions.

1. Differences between using a `map` for the same logic and using a `flatMap`
   I understood that maps operate synchronously and flatMap operates asynchronously. If so, isn't it necessary to write code asynchronously to see the maximum performance benefit?
   For example, what are the differences when using a Flux object called sample as follows?

```
sample.map { it.convertToOther() }

sample.map { Flux.just(it.convertToOther()) }
```

2. Multiple requests from the client must be processed, or Collection must be used to communicate with the DB. I know that the `Collection.map()` api also works synchronously, but can performance degradation occur if used instead of `Flux`?

2.1. How about using `Flux.map()` or `Collection.map()` inside `Flux.flatMap()`?